# ServiceStack: SerializationException

Tags: servicestack

I am testing the api created using ServiceStack using SoapUI and when I try to send the required DataMember thru headers, the api returns the correct values. When I try to send the required DataMember thru Body, I am getting the below error... Please help

Request sent through the body

```
<GetProductDetailsReq>
<AToken>ck0b0YYBPkrnVF/j6e16DUPzxLX2SMCXewoR4T</AToken>
</GetProductDetailsReq>

POST http://localhost/ServiceStackAPI/GetProductDetails HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Content-Length: 777
Host: localhost
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

**Response Status**

> Error Code
>       SerializationException Message
>       Could not deserialize 'application/xml' request using ServiceModel.DTO.GetProductDetailsReq' Error:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1
>   position 66. Expecting element 'GetProductDetailsReq' from namespace
>   ''.. Encountered 'Element' with name 'GetProductDetailsReq', namespace
>   'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types'. at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream
>   stream) at ServiceStack.Text.XmlSerializer.DeserializeFromStream(Type
>   type, Stream stream) at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.CreateContentTypeRequest(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, Type requestType, String contentType) Stack Trace
>       at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.CreateContentTypeRequest(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, Type requestType, String contentType) at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, IRestPath restPath) at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest
>   httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [SOAP Limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) to ensure you're creating Services that can be sent in SOAP, i.e. If the Request DTO is called `GetProductDetails` then it must return a Response DTO called `GetProductDetailsResponse`. Also you need to ensure your DTO's have `[DataContract]` on all types and `[DataMember]` on all public properties and that your DTO's are in a [single namespace](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#single-wsdl-namespace).

The other issue with this request is that you're using the SOAP requests to wrong endpoint address. i.e. The SOAP endpoint is either `/soap11` or `/soap12`. In the above example it's attempting to send it to the `/GetProductDetails` custom HTTP route, when for SOAP it needs to be either `/soap11` or `soap12`.

If you did just want to just send XML over HTTP then you should just send the raw XML payload which you can find out what it looks like by serializing the Request DTO, e.g:

```
string requestXml = new GetProductDetails { ... }.ToXml();
```

Which you can easily send with [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils):

```
var responseXml = "http://localhost/ServiceStackAPI/GetProductDetails"
    .PostXmlToUrl(xmlRequest);

var responseDto = responseXml.FromXml<GetProductDetailsResponse>();
```

Assuming you have a `[Route("/GetProductDetails")]` defined on the `GetProductDetails` Request DTO.